# Showing two different definitions of a primitive root are the same

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

In a book im reading the following definition is given for a primitive root:

"An integer $a$ is called a primitive root mod $p$ if $\overline{ a }$  generates the group $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. Equivalently, $a$ is a primitive root mod $p$ if $p-1$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \text{ mod } p$."

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding why these two definitions are equivilant. Would anybody be able to explain why?

Comment: Do you know how many elements $U(ℤ/pℤ)$ has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $p$ is a prime, the group $U(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$ has prder $p-1$. So if the group is cyclic and has a generator $a$ (it is, and does, but that's a different theorem), then $a$ must necessarily have order $p-1$. Conversely, if there is an element $a$ of order $p-1$, it must necessarily generate the whole group.

Comment: I see, so if $a$ is a primitive root (according to the second definition), then it must necessarily have order $p-1$ in $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. Therefore, it is a generator of $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. And the other way round, if $a$ is a generator of $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, then it must have order $p-1$, which gives us that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \text{ mod  } p$. Is this the right way of thinking about it?

Comment: @xyz-x I don't know if it is _the_ right way of thinking about it. There are often many ways to think about the same thing. But from what I can read in your comment it seems like a _good_ way, and more or less what I had in mind.